# cannot get string inside an element - object literal javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to to get the strings of two divs `.class-date` and `.class-time`  but i'm getting an Uncaught TypeError "e.siblings is not a function". This probably a rudimentary mistake but I can't work it out. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated .

```js
var Cc = {
    init: function() {
        Cc.bindEvent();
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
        $('.book-class').on("click", function() {
            let selectedclass = this;
            Cc.parseClass(selectedclass);
        });
    },
    parseClass: function(selectedclass) {
        let classdate = selectedclass.siblings('.class-date').text();
        let classtime = selectedclass.siblings('.class-time').text();
        console.log(classdate, classtime);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    Cc.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
    <div class="class-date">Thursday, 1 January</div>
    <div class="class-time">18:00 — 20:00</div>
    <div class="book-class">Book Class</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not a jQuery object. It is the DOM object of the clicked item.

Use `$(this)` and to make it even clearer, add a `$` on the vars to show you expect and process a jQuery object

```js
var Cc = {
    init: function() {
        Cc.bindEvent();
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
        $('.book-class').on("click", function() {
            let $selectedclass = $(this);
            Cc.parseClass($selectedclass);
        });
    },
    parseClass: function($selectedclass) {
        let classdate = $selectedclass.siblings('.class-date').text();
        let classtime = $selectedclass.siblings('.class-time').text();
        console.log(classdate, classtime);
    }
}

$(function() {
    Cc.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">
    <div class="class-date">Thursday, 1 January</div>
    <div class="class-time">18:00 — 20:00</div>
    <div class="book-class">Book Class</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `click` callback function, `this` is a HTMLElement and you're treating it like a jQuery object.

Change `let selectedclass = this;` to `let selectedclass = $(this);`

Comment: thank you taking the time to reply, this was indeed the problem

Comment: @CalAlt Sure. I'm glad I could help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could also skip the anonymous function in `bindEvent` click handler and pass `CC.parseClass` as reference instead. It will change the context of `this` inside `parseClass` to the element the event occurred on which may or may not be confusing regarding using `this`

```
var Cc = {
    init: function() {
        Cc.bindEvent();
    },
    bindEvent: function() {
        $('.book-class').on("click", Cc.parseClass);
    },
    parseClass: function(event) {
        // `this` is element from event handler
        let $selectedclass = $(this);
        let classdate = $selectedclass.siblings('.class-date').text();
        let classtime = $selectedclass.siblings('.class-time').text();
        console.log(classdate, classtime);
    }
}

$(function() {
    Cc.init();
});
```